# CASE WHEN is always evaluating ELSE value when used in a insert statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This AFTER INSERT TRIGGER always evaluates to OrderTotal

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OrderInformationInsert]
ON [dbo].[Order]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO [FRTOOLS_Orders]
                (OrderNumber,
                 SubTotal)
    SELECT i.[OrderNumber],
           CASE
             WHEN SUM(oc.Amount) > 0
               THEN i.OrderTotal - SUM(oc.Amount)
             ELSE i.OrderTotal
           END AS subTotal
    FROM   inserted i
           LEFT JOIN [OrderCharge] oc
             ON i.OrderID = oc.OrderID
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT '1'
                      FROM   [FRTOOLS_Orders]
                      WHERE  OrderNumber = i.[OrderNumber])
    GROUP  BY i.[OrderNumber],
              i.[OrderTotal]
```

When I run the the select statement. I get the information as expected?

```
SELECT o.[OrderNumber],
       CASE
         WHEN SUM(oc.Amount) > 0
           THEN o.OrderTotal - SUM(oc.Amount)
         ELSE o.OrderTotal
       END AS subTotal
FROM   [Order] o
       LEFT JOIN [OrderCharge] oc
         ON o.OrderID = oc.OrderID
GROUP  BY o.[OrderNumber],
          o.[OrderTotal]
```

Would this be the case if the OrderCharge table has no values yet and how does FROM INSERTED [work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx), Should I be going at this in a different direction.

OrderCharge Table Scripted out:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderCharge](
[OrderChargeID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1021,1000) NOT NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[OrderID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Amount] [money] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderCharge] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[OrderChargeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderCharge]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderCharge_Order] FOREIGN KEY([OrderID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderCharge] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderCharge_Order]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'2' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'OrderCharge', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Amount'
GO
```

I'm not sure but Order Table I very long? By the way this is not our Database this part of Shipworks software and yes they named a table a sql keyword which is why we have to manipulate the table.

```
USE [ShipWorks]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Order]    Script Date: 2/18/2017 11:23:20 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [OrderID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1006,1000) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [StoreID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OrderNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OrderNumberComplete] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OrderTotal] [money] NOT NULL,
    [LocalStatus] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IsManual] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OnlineLastModified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [OnlineCustomerID] [sql_variant] NULL,
    [OnlineStatus] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [OnlineStatusCode] [sql_variant] NULL,
    [RequestedShipping] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BillFirstName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [BillMiddleName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [BillLastName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [BillCompany] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [BillStreet1] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [BillStreet2] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [BillStreet3] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [BillCity] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BillStateProvCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BillPostalCode] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [BillCountryCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BillPhone] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [BillFax] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [BillEmail] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [BillWebsite] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BillAddressValidationSuggestionCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BillAddressValidationStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BillAddressValidationError] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [BillResidentialStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BillPOBox] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BillUSTerritory] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BillMilitaryAddress] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipFirstName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ShipMiddleName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ShipLastName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ShipCompany] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [ShipStreet1] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [ShipStreet2] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [ShipStreet3] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [ShipCity] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ShipStateProvCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ShipPostalCode] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ShipCountryCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ShipPhone] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [ShipFax] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [ShipEmail] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ShipWebsite] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ShipAddressValidationSuggestionCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipAddressValidationStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipAddressValidationError] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [ShipResidentialStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipPOBox] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipUSTerritory] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipMilitaryAddress] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RollupItemCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RollupItemName] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [RollupItemCode] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [RollupItemSKU] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RollupItemLocation] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [RollupItemQuantity] [float] NULL,
    [RollupItemTotalWeight] [float] NOT NULL,
    [RollupNoteCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BillNameParseStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BillUnparsedName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ShipNameParseStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipUnparsedName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ShipSenseHashKey] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [ShipSenseRecognitionStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipAddressType] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Customer]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Store] FOREIGN KEY([StoreID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Store] ([StoreID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Store]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'4' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'StoreID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditName', @value=N'Store' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'StoreID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'4' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'CustomerID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditName', @value=N'Customer' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'CustomerID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'1' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'OrderNumber'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditName', @value=N'Order Number' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'OrderNumberComplete'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'2' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'OrderTotal'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'1' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'OnlineCustomerID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'1' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'OnlineStatusCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'5' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'BillStateProvCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditName', @value=N'BillState' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'BillStateProvCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'6' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'BillCountryCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditName', @value=N'BillCountry' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'BillCountryCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'5' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ShipStateProvCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditName', @value=N'ShipState' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ShipStateProvCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'6' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ShipCountryCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditName', @value=N'ShipCountry' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ShipCountryCode'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'1' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'BillNameParseStatus'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuditFormat', @value=N'1' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Order', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ShipNameParseStatus'
GO
```

Comment: This might be the answer I'm not sure, but could the [OrderCharge] table not have a value yet?

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: I'm not sure, would that be the case if the selct stament when ran reuturns the correct value and the insert statement does not. This is a AFTER INSERT trigger.

Comment: There being a trigger involved is one of those important facts that you want to include in your question. It also helps if you supply some sample data. Walls of ANSI spaghetti code doesn't usually give too many clues as to why results are incorrect.

Comment: "How does FROM INSERTED work"? What's the actual business logic behind doing this trigger?

From the code provided, my guess is that when you run the query over the table as a whole you get the expected results as there are some rows where oc.Amount sums to >0. But in the specific case of the insert trigger, that isn't the case (e.g. it isn't matched). I'm not confident enough to post this as an answer given the information provided, though.

Comment: Does the [OrderCharge] table have a matching value at this point? Or not? If it's empty or doesn't match the "inserted" row, then left-joining to it will give a NULL result so then you won't get the expected subtotal.

Comment: Well in 'worked' I was assuming that all data that was committed was stored in temp table and was accessed through inserted table. Wouldn't that mean that the OrderCharge table in my case was already committed as well and could be accessed. The problem here is this is a limited access database that hinders me in seeing whats going on.

Comment: Are you sure the records are in [OrderCharge] *before* the insert?

Comment: Please post a **complete** example that demonstrates the issue you are asking about (with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the system does an INSERT into the Order table and then an INSERT into the OrderCharge table.

If you want to capture information about the charges, you will need to do it after the INSERT in the OrderCharge table.